# Applying a custom style to a spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am trying to apply a custom style over a spinner:

```
Spinner classClassification = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.classClassification);
Resources res = getResources();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_custom, res.getStringArray(classArrayResource));
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_layout);
classClassification.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

`in spinner_custom:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

`in spinner_dropdown_layout:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_5"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

And in `styles`:

```
<!--Spinner Style-->
<style name="spinnerItemStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:layout_height">40sp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">55sp</item>
</style>

<style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:layout_height">40sp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">55sp</item>
</style>
```

But no change in above takes effect in the outcome, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that the problem is in the TextView in spinner_custom.  You should set the style equal to @style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style:="@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```